# What is this component, labelled as "RT" on the PCB?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

Can someone tell me the name of the below component? It is labelled as RT on the PCB:

[image: Photo of component]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be a Littelfuse SMD resettable fuse.

> The miniSMD series provides surface mount overcurrent protection for applications where space is at a premium and resettable protection is desired.

https://www.littelfuse.com/products/polyswitch-resettable-ptcs/surface-mount/minismd.aspx

Comment: Do you know , what is this component use for ?

Comment: I've edited this answer to include some additional information about the part from the manufacturer product page.

Comment: It is generally used for protection against over currents. Could have been put as the first precaution against overcurrent, excessive inrush current. Was it close to the power input?